# Why is H2 slow when updating Blobs?

Tags: java, jdbc, blob, h2

I need some sort of persistance componnent to store id(long) and value(object) for my Java application.

All The cacheing systems I looked at where not persistant enough(If the process died the cache would erase itself) or slow

I tried to use Embedded DataBases like Derby and HSQLDB but they where not as fast as H2 as SELECT and INSERT.

For some reason the UPDATE query takes 1-2 seconds for one row if I Update a row with Blob.

Does anyone know why is it this slow?

Queries:

```
CREATE TABLE ENTITIES(ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, DATA BLOB)
INSERT INTO ENTITIES(DATA, ID) VALUES(?, ?)
UPDATE ENTITIES SET DATA = ? WHERE ID = ?
```

I am using JDBC with `PreparedStatement`

Edit:

The connection string is:

```
jdbc:h2:C:\temp\h2db;FILE_LOCK=NO;
```

I tried to add `CACHE_SIZE=102400` and `PAGE_SIZE=209715200` but it didn't help

Comment: What is the blob?  How big is it?  Is anything indexed in entities?  How is the H2 data stored on disk?

Comment: The field DATA is the BLOB. The size is a sirialized Java Object with 2 Strings of 100 and byte[] of 100. PRIMARY KEY defines an index. I defined in th connection string that the gile shuld be C:\temp...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior about greetings on StackOverflow.

Comment: The `FILE_LOCK=NO` is very dangerous. And such a large page size doesn't make sense. I would re-create the database and try again. If it still takes so long, please get a full thread dump while it is running (in a loop or so).

Comment: 1. I know. 2. I tried using jvisualvm and saw that the alot of time is wasted on some page function with the java.niomFile.read method